# German 'for' + subject + 'to' in sentences

Tags: preposition

I was wondering if this is how you say 'for' + subject + 'to' in German, because of the different constructions in English and German:

> Ich werde sie auf dem Boden lassen, für den Raumpfleger, aufzuheben.
>
> *I will leave them on the floor **for** the cleaner **to** pick up.*

---

> Wenn ich das mache, wird es härter sein, für ihn, mir zu helfen.
>
> *If I do it, it will be harder **for** him **to** help me.*

Answer (score 2):

The exact same structure exists in German: `für ... zu/zum ...`.

> *I will leave them on the floor for the cleaner to pick up.*
>
> Ich lasse sie auf dem Boden liegen, für die Putzfrau zum Aufsammeln.

This is grammatically correct, but a German would probably rephrase it with `damit` (so that) instead.

> Ich lasse sie auf dem Boden liegen, damit die Putzfrau sie aufsammeln kann.

---

> *If I do it, it will be harder for him to help me.*
>
> Wenn ich das mache, wird es für ihn schwerer sein<sub>(</sub>,<sub>)</sub> mir zu helfen.

Comment: I edited in some commas, but I really didn't know what to do with the first German translation (in terms of orthography), so maybe someone else can help with that. Also I don't think it's the "exact same" structure - at least it's not as idiomatic. Try translating "for the car to start faster", for instance.

Comment: @Takkat Still doesn't look right/grammatically correct. At least it's *very* colloquial. Technically, it should be something like "Ich lasse sie für die Putzfrau am Boden liegen, zum Aufsammeln." Also possible (but not in the sense of the question): Ich lasse sie auf dem Boden liegen, für die Putzfrau, zum Aufsammeln.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: I totally agree that the first example is not good style but as I understand it it's meant as an examplatory possibility using a similar construct in German. Using *damit* is certaily the better way (*"damit das Auto schneller startet"*).

Comment: Ich würde zwei Sätze machen: Ich laß das liegen. Die Putzfrau bringt das schon in Ordnung.

Comment: The second example ("it will be harder for him to help me") doesn't seem to hit the point, really, as it is a different construction both in English and German.

Answer (score 2):

The English construction with for + accusative + to-infinitive can't be translated with the same construction in German.

> This text is too difficult for me to translate. - Die Übersetzung dieses Textes ist zu schwer/ schwierig für mich.
>
> He waited for them to sit down. - Er wartete bis sich alle gesetzt hatten.
>
> He arranged for a taxi to get her to the station. Er bestellte ihr ein Taxi zum Bahnhof.

As you see there is no 1 to 1 correspondence between the English and the German translation.

Comment: Der Text ist zu schwer für mich zu verstehen. ... The construction does exist. It's just less common and sounds a bit colloquial in many cases.

Comment: Sorry, ich würde das nie sagen. Klingt nach Wort für Wort Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Ich würde sagen: Der Text ist mir zu schwer. Ich versteh das nicht.

Comment: "https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=%22zu+schwer+f%C3%BCr+mich+zu+*%22"   nicht jeder Treffer ist auch ein Beispiel, aber es ist ziemlich offensichtlich, dass die Wendung verwendet wird.

Comment: OK, also irgendwie funktioniert der LInk nicht. Gib einfach bei Google ein: "zu schwer für mich zu *", inklusive der Anführungsstriche